# Prevent users from changing the parameter ID in the Edit action method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

So my URL on the Edit/Details Method looks this http://localhost:1234/Movies/Edit?ID=3. If the db table contains records that belongs to someone else say 1, 2, 4, 5, 6.  There is nothing stopping the user from directly typing and accessing say record 6 (eg /Movie/Edit/6).

How can I prevent that from happening?

```
        // GET: /Movie/Edit/id
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Movie movie = db.Movies.Find(id);
        if (movie == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(movie);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Movie/Edit/id
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Movie movie)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(movie).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(movie);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `If the db table contains records that **belongs** to someone else`?. If you have a relationship between users and movies, add an explanation of that matter in the question.

Comment: Sorry I was kind of vague. Here screenshot of the two table maybe it will give you a better idea after looking at it. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j49irncej1fue1d/tables.png  In the above example I can login as a different user1/user2 and I am able to replace the  7 to 34 and switch it around. Something seems wrong with the way I am doing it.

Comment: Ok. In your question, you haven't written any code to verify which user can see/edit which movies. In each Action method you should verify those permissions before doing anything else.

Comment: You mean adding  something like 'Movie movie = db.Movies.Where(x => x.FKID ="cc4eeec8-0702-4c97-bc51-2d52e66f5f64").Find(id);' when getting the id. Do you have an example?

Comment: @ceci If I understand your question correctly, you can simply do `db.Movies.Where(x => x.FKID == "cc4eeec8-0702-4c97-bc51-2d52e66f5f64" && x.TransactionID == id).FirstOrDefault();` If it returns null user is not authorized and you can throw unauthroized exception.